# How to setup open graph so share on Facebook shows up as photo?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Trying to share a URL on Facebook that displays as a photo in the news feed, like what Flickr is doing. For instance, if you try to share this url on Facebook: https://www.flickr.com/photos/kylesipple/17537472375/

It shows up like this:

[image: Example Facebook Photo share]

Using the open graph explorer/debugger, I don't see anything too terribly special with that page's meta tags:

[image: Example meta tags]

Any one have ideas on what's needed to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what are you asking exactly. If it is simply how to share a URL on Facebook that displays as a photo in the newsfeed you just need to set the proper Open Graphs tags (i.e. og:image). If it is something else, can you clarify?

You can find more information about photo sharing here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images